# Trying to connect with openweather api but SSLHandshakeException occurs

Tags: android, json, openweathermap

Here is how am trying to connect to openweathermap

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String jsonData;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try{
        JsonDownloader jsonDownloader = new JsonDownloader();
        jsonData = jsonDownloader.execute("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02").get();   
        Log.i("Json data downloaded : ",jsonData);//trying to print json data to logcat
        }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
//below is class to download json data 
public class JsonDownloader extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    InputStream inputStream;
    String jsonData;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            int data = inputStreamReader.read();
            while(data != -1){
                char currentChar = (char)data;
                jsonData+=currentChar;
                data = inputStreamReader.read();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return null;
    }
}
```

Exact Exception : java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
Also i want to know is it okay to catch multiple exceptions with single 'Exception' class instead of exact exception type class.

Comment: what the device api version you re testing your app on ?

Comment: API 17 (Droid4x emulator)

Comment: Good i guess thats the problem , it has to do with apis lower than 21 , can you try it on device with api 21 or older and tell me how it goes ?

Comment: i tried it with api 28 & exception is gone but i dont get json data at logcat

Comment: for the json data , try to log if you re getting data from your data source , and make sure you re connecting properly to the data source , are you trying to get data from api ?

Comment: Yes am trying to get the data from api

Comment: did you try to log your data , are you receiving any data from you api , why don't you use retrofit instead ?

Comment: yes jsonData String is null , am new to android i'll checkout retrofit.

Comment: Okey , take look at it